# How to reference ubuntu file names in unicode correctly within PHP shell_exec function calling Tika

Tags: php, unicode, exec, apache-tika, shell-exec

OS: Ubuntu 18.04; PHP 7.2； tika: tika-app-1.22.jar; Java:
openjdk version "1.8.0_222

sample-2.pdf, sample-2-文字.pdf, sample-2-でした.pdf, sample-2-수요.pdf are identical pdf files located in the same directory. Tika 1.22 is used to extract the meta information from the pdf file. In a Linux terminal, Tika command line list below can generate correct outputs for all pdf files.

```
$ java -jar /opt/tika-app-1.22.jar -j sample-2.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null

$ java -jar /opt/tika-app-1.22.jar -j sample-2-文字.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null

$ java -jar /opt/tika-app-1.22.jar -j sample-2-でした.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null

$ java -jar /opt/tika-app-1.22.jar -j sample-2-수요.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null
```

Using `shell_exec()` and `exec()` functions from a PHP program to execute the same set of commands, however, yields different results.

Please see the PHP code below:

```
<?php

$output1 = shell_exec('java -jar /opt/tika.jar -j sample-2.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null');
echo "<pre>$output1</pre>";

$output2C = shell_exec('java -jar /opt/tika.jar -j sample-2-文字.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null');
echo "<pre>$output2C</pre>";

$output2J = shell_exec('java -jar /opt/tika.jar -j sample-2-でした.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null');
echo "<pre>$output2J</pre>";

$output2K = shell_exec('java -jar /opt/tika.jar -j sample-2-수요.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null');
echo "<pre>$output2K</pre>";

$c1 = exec('java -jar /opt/tika.jar -j sample-2.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null', $output3, $r);
echo "<pre>$output3</pre><br> $c1 <br> $r";

$c2 = exec('java -jar /opt/tika.jar -j sample-2-文字.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null', $output4C, $r);
echo "<pre>$output4C</pre><br> $c2 <br> $r";

$c2 = exec('java -jar /opt/tika.jar -j sample-2-でした.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null', $output4J, $r);
echo "<pre>$output4J</pre><br> $c2 <br> $r";

$c2 = exec('java -jar /opt/tika.jar -j sample-2-수요.pdf >&1 2>/dev/null', $output4K, $r);
echo "<pre>$output4K</pre><br> $c2 <br> $r";
?>
```

`$ouput1` gives intended output, while `$output2C`, `$output2J`, `$output2K`yields nothing. The only difference is the file names contain some CJK characters or not.

Tried to confirmed the results using `exec()` function, please see the code above, `$output3` yiels the intended results and `$output4C`, `$output4J`, `$output4K` only gives an empty array. Both $output1 and $output3 give the intended results. The only difference with exec() function again is that three file names contain CJK characters, and a file name is entirely in ASCII characters.

The file name strings as the parameters used in both `shell_exec()` and `exec()` functions are all shown in `UTF-8` encoding, with or without the Chinese characters, verified thru `mb_detect_encoding()` function in PHP.

No error message is given in the Apache error.log. The only root cause is narrowed down to the CJK Unicode characters in the file names, here I do mean CJK characters, not just Chinese but also Japanese and Korean.

The reason I directed stderr 2>/dev/null is because Tika generated the following warning messages:

```
Oct 31, 2019 8:51:47 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed.
See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
for optional dependencies.

Oct 31, 2019 8:51:47 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: org.xerial`s sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.
```

which are not of interests and have no messages about why PHP shell_exec and exec did not yield any outputs. These warning messages are captured from the command line execution. If I removed `>&1 2>/dev/null` from the `shell_exec` and `exec` from the above code, the same warning messages are given in the case where file names contains no CJK characters. Where the file names contain CJK characters, nothing displayed which is identical to having `>&1 2>/dev/null` in the `shell_exec` and `exec` calls.

Also did some comparison with straight forward Linux commands, such as cat, with or without unicode CJK characters in the file names, both PHP `shell_exec()` and `exec()` behave correctly. It seems only when java is called via shell_exec and exec functions, mis-interpreting files names occurs! This is really puzzling!

Question: What's the correct way to reference a Linux file name containing Unicode CJK characters in the PHP `shell_exec()` and `exec()` functions when calling Tika, thus, when shell_exec and exec passes the shell commands to Linux, Linux and java could interpret the file name correctly?

Appreciate greatly for any hints, solutions, and pointing to the right directions. Deep Bows.

Comment: How is `2>/dev/null` helping your debugging? System, shell, Java locale?

Comment: Mario, thanks for askiing, removing >&1 2>/dev/null from the shell_exec and exec calls, didn't yeild any hints for the spacific errors. In the case file names contains no CJK characters, Tika output is identical to that of the command line. In the case, where file name contains CJK characters, simply, no outputs as having >&1 2>/dev/null in the shell_exec and exec calls

Comment: To really capture stderr: [How can I debug exec() problems?](//stackoverflow.com/a/45784653), though if Java yields no stacktraces you're out of luck. Then experiment with [Setting java locale settings](//stackoverflow.com/q/64038)

Comment: Mario, thanks for the pointing. I redirected stderr to stdout and execute php line by line via php -a mode. No specific errors displayed. In interactive mode, php executed well for filenames with or without CJK characters. The problem seems to be how PHP shell_exec() and exec() function passing filenames to Java and how Java receives the filenames. Whether or not system locale is set to English (United States) or one of the CJK languages, still didn't solve the problem. It's really puzzling!